# how to use lists elements as a range for string search?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists containing numbers that represents line numbers in a text file,

i.e.

```
list1 = [ '1' , '9',  '15']
list2 = [ '7' , '12',  '22']
```

I wanted to use these numbers as a range for a string search, I wanted to assign `list1` to `starting_line` and `list2` to `ending_line` but when I try to run it it doesn't accept a list.

```
search_results=[]
for line in lines[starting_line:ending_line]:
            if 'error ' in line and fail_lines < len(list1):
                line = line.rstrip()
                search_results.append(line)
```

My goal is to scan through the list and then run the search so for example

```
for line in lines[1:7]: and then [9:12] , [15:22]
           if 'error ' in line and fail_lines < len(list1):
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    search_results.append(line)
```

What should I change or add in my code right now?

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: the items in the list are not numbers - they are strings

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the code in a loop that iterates through each element in the list.

```py
search result = []
for starting_line, ending_line in zip(list1,list2):
    for line in lines[int(starting_line):int(ending_line)]:
            if 'error ' in line and fail_lines < len(list1):
                line = line.rstrip()
                search_results.append(line)
```